# Generate predictors with fixed predictive validity in R

Tags: r, logistic

Let's say I have a dataset:

```
x=rnorm(1000, mean=0, sd=10)
```

I would like to create five variables `(a,b,c,d,e)` that I can use to predict `x`.

I would like to have a fixed predictive validity for each variable, let's say:

`.56, .45, .36,.23,.10.`

What's the easiest way of doing this in R?

Comment: The trick is to create the variables `a` through `e` first and *then* compute `x` from them.  An example (actually 6000 of them) appears in the `R` code at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52502/how-to-represent-trend-over-time/60626#60626.

Comment: yes that's straightforward but is there a way to go backwards and create the predictors from a fixed dataset?

Comment: In certain cases, subject to mathematical limitations, that is possible. Could you explain what you mean by "predictive validity"? Are these correlation coefficients, partial correlations, or something else?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't say that. these are regression coefficients.

Comment: Are they for regressions *separately* for `x` on each variable or multiple regression coefficients?  Are they standardized or not?

Comment: they are multiple regression coefficients lm(y~a+b+c+d+e), each predictor is a combination of the dependent variable (y) and random error with different standard deviations for each predictor.

Comment: That sounds rather mixed up, because it makes no sense to predict `y` from variables that involve `y` itself!